Is change of variables formula for signed measures valid also for functions with infinite integral?
Let $\mu$ be a signed measure on $X$ with Jordan decomposition $\mu^+-\mu^-$, $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ a measurable map, $\pi_\#\mu$ the pushforward measure of $\mu$ with respect to $\pi$. If $f:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu$ exists (even if it's not finite), I am wondering if is it true that also $\int_Yf\, d\pi_\#\mu$ exists and we have the equality
$$\int_Yf\, d\pi_\#\mu=\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu.$$
Since the formula works if $\mu$ is a nonnegative measure, we know that the fact that $\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu$ exists means that at least one between $\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu^+,\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu^-$ is finite, so their difference is well defined. So we can use the formula for the nonnegative measure in the following way
$$\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu=\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu^+-\int_Xf\circ\pi\, d\mu^-=\int_Yf\, d\pi_\#(\mu^+)-\int_Yf\, d\pi_\#(\mu^-)=\int_Yf\, d\pi_\#\mu.$$
I'm not sure this is correct since despite the equality $\pi_\#\mu=\pi_\#(\mu^+)-\pi_\#(\mu^-)$, this is not necessarily the Jordan decomposition of $\pi_\#\mu$.

$\int fd(\mu_1-\mu_2)=\int fd\mu_1-\int fd\mu_2$ if one of the terms on the right is finite. This  is true for any positive measures $\mu_1$ amd $\mu_2$. Hence, your proof is fine. [Take $\mu_1=\pi_\#(\mu^+)$ and $\mu_2=\pi_\#(\mu^-)$].
